# Função equivalente à "DISTINCT ON" em BD Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

No Postgres, você pode fazer com que o distinct se aplique a apenas 1 campo do select utilizando o `DISTINC ON`, como posso reproduzir essa função em um banco de dados Oracle?

Segue uma query de exemplo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CITY) CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE, ROW_ID FROM db.BILLADDRESS
```

Gostaria de montá-la mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CITY) CITY || ';' || STATE || ';' || ZIPCODE || ';' || ROW_ID FROM db.BILLADDRESS
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme [está resposta do SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515397/1518921) (perdoe-me eu traduzi rapidamente de olho, assim que possivel reviso se houver alguma falha):

O mesmo efeito pode ser replicado no Oracle ou usando [`first_value()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm) ou usando um dos [`rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions129.htm#SQLRF00690) ou [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#SQLRF06100).

Ambas as variantes também trabalham em PostgreSQL.

**`first_value()`**

```
select distinct col1, 
first_value(col2) over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc)
from tmp
```

`first_value` pega o primeiro valor para a partição, mas repete para cada linha, por isso é necessário para usá-lo em combinação com `distinct` para obter uma única linha para cada partição.

**`row_number()` / `rank()`**

```
select col1, col2 from (
  select col1, col2, 
  row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc) as rownumber 
  from tmp
) foo
where rownumber = 1
```

Troca `row_number()` com `rank()` esto é um exemplo produz o mesmo resultado.

Uma característica da variação é que você pode usar para buscar as **N primeiras** 
para uma especifica partição
(e.g. "3 ultimas atualizações") simplesmente trocando `rownumber = 1` por `rownumber <= N`.

Comment: Eu vi essa pergunta, mas meu problema está em usar o select em várias colunas e não apenas em 2. Tentei umas variações como essa `SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(CITY) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY ORDER BY 1) AS CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE, ROW_ID FROM db.BILLADDRESS` mas não funcionou.

Comment: @EduardoSilva Eu não entendo bem de Oracle, mas ao meu ver o segundo exemplo `select col1, col2 from (
  select col1, col2, 
  row_number() over ...` é totalmente funcional, bastaria você mudar para algo como: `select col1, col2, col3 from (
  select col1, col2, col3,
  row_number() over ...`. Perdoe-me *se* não entendi.

Comment: consegui o resultado que buscava adicionando o trecho `FIRST_VALUE(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)` para cada coluna do meu select (col2, col3, ..), vou adicionar uma resposta com a query em questão, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Com a ajuda da resposta do [@Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) consegui montar o `SELECT` de maneira correta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY || ';' || 
    FIRST_VALUE(STATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) || ';' || 
    FIRST_VALUE(ZIPCODE) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) || ';' || 
    FIRST_VALUE(ROW_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) 
  FROM db.BILLADDRESS 
ORDER BY 1
```

Repetindo o `FIRST_VALUE(colX) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)` para cada coluna do meu `SELECT`, onde **colX** é a coluna em que você deseja aplicar o `DISTINCT`.